# Update SingleSalesforce Object if subscribers are lead or contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have 2 opt-out flags in Salesforce at level of Leads and Contacts. I would like to update subscriber preferences based on these two types. The opt-out process will be implemented in a Cloud Page for both types. I´m trying this but it doesn't work out in order to publish the Cloud Page. I suppose that there is an error in the AMPscript code:

```javascript
%%[
    VAR @rowset3, @row3, @value3, @lookupvalue,@Updatelead 
    SET @rowset3 = LookupRows("Lead_SFDC_AUTO2", "_ContactKey", _subscriberkey) 
    SET @row3 = Row(@rowset3,1) 
    SET @Value3 = Field(@row3, "_ContactKey")
    SET @lookupvalue = Attributevalue("_subscriberkey")
    VAR @rowset2, @row2, @value2, @Updatecontact 
    SET @rowset2 = LookupRows("Account_SFDC_AUTO", "PersonContactId", _subscriberkey) 
    SET @row2 = Row(@rowset2,1) 
    SET @Value2 = Field(@row2, "PersonContactId")
    IF @Value3 == @lookupvalue THEN
        SET @Updatelead = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Lead', @lookupvalue, 'LE_LOPD__c', 'false') 
    ELSEIF @Value2 == @lookupvalue THEN
        SET @Updatecontact = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Account', @lookupvalue, 'AC_LOPD__c', 'false')
    ENDIF
]%%
<div>
%%[IF @lookupvalue == @value3 THEN]%%
    @Updatelead
        ELSE
    @Updatecontact
%%[ENDIF]%%
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the error you are getting or the exact problem you are facing, as this will help identifying and solving your issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention any specific problem, but one thing I can say for sure is, that the following won't work:

```javascript
%%[IF @lookupvalue == @value3 THEN]%%
    @Updatelead
        ELSE
    @Updatecontact
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

This is because you try to use AMPscript-variables outside of an AMPscript-block. To output the value of the variables try this

```javascript
%%[
    IF @lookupvalue == @value3 THEN
        V(@Updatelead)
    ELSE
        V(@Updatecontact)
    ENDIF
]%%
```

or this

```javascript
%%[IF @lookupvalue == @value3 THEN]%%
    %%=V(@Updatelead)=%%
%%[ELSE]%%
    %%=V(@Updatecontact)=%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

instead.